# Camera Firmware not installed on GT-I9515L

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, camera

### TL;DR

My Rear Camera doesn't work and the Firmware version for it is `null` and I think I need to install it manually. How do I do that in a Samsung Galaxy S4 GT-I9515L with `PDA I9515LUBU1BOJ1` and `CSC I9515LZTM1BOI1`?

---

Everytime I open my camera app, I get a black screen and some of those times it shows a **Updating Camera Firmware. Please Wait...**

When researching the web,  I found the `*#0*#` code that tells me **Data Line Fail** and **Camera Failed** when I hit the **Mega Cam** buttom.

Also, the `*#34971539#` code shows me that I have no firmware installed:

```
Rear Camera (Main)
Cam FW Ver: null
Phone FW Ver: S13F0LAGE10
```

What I tried:

- Factory Reset. After this, the Google Account got in and re-installed every app and restored every data, but I didn't consider this being the problem due to the **Cam FW Ver: null** appearing to state that I have no Camera Firmware currently installed.
- Phone Firmware Update. I found a Firmware on SamMobiles that matches my Country and Carrier dated 2 weeks ago for Android 5.0.1. I know I hadn't gotten this from OTA because although I use `TIM` carrier, my phone had the `Claro` carrier logo, so technically my provider and the firmware didn't match each other. I successfully installed the 5.0.1 firmware and the phone works perfectly, except the camera problem that still persists (no Firmware version).

My guess is that I have to install the camera firmware manually, but I have no idea how to do it. I'd love if somebody could point me to the direction in which I can find the solution.

When opening the app, it gives some freezes, but it's possible to hit the switch camera and use the front camera regularly.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried updating the camera firmware from that *#34971539# menue? use the [**second option which you can see here**](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=48041401&postcount=6)

Comment: @benjaminS in my case, it's the 3rd button and it's disabled along with almost all buttons in that menu.

Comment: when did this problem occur? have you had any damaged hardware or replaced something on your device? seems really weird to me

Comment: @benjaminS I believe before I installed the 5.0.1 firmware, all those buttons were enabled (which was yesterday), but I didn't pay attention to any of them and I thought that updating the phone firmware could solve it all. But the actual problem in the camera has been happening for about 1 month now, I just was too busy with other stuffs to set aside some time to play with it and see if I can get a fix. My biggest problem now is that I can't access Web Whatsapp because the QR Code uses the camera and the camera seems to be uninstalled (no firmware).

Comment: Maybe [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2336927&page=2) can give some pointers?

Comment: @beeshyams I have gone through all pages of that thread. Although a few people seems to suffers from the same problem as me (null on camera firmware), no solution for it were provided.

Comment: Some [inputs](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s5/help/camera-firmware-thread-t2832384) different model

Comment: @beeshyams that seems to be a dead thread since the OP never replied anyone and nobody posted back a success message reply. Also, the procedure he proposes require files which he doesn't provide. I don't know how to perform those steps in my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I could not find a *software* solution, so I took it to the warranty and they fixed it by replacing the camera.